# Get-ChildItem of HKLM returns less results for Windows Powershell than for Developer Powershell for VS2019

Tags: powershell

When I execute the following command in "Windows Powershell", I get around 270 results. When I execute the same command in "Developer Powershell for VS2019" on the same machine, I get close to a 1000 results. How can I modify the "Windows Powershell" to behave like the "Developer Powershell" (as the developer powershell application isn't available on all machines)?

```
gci "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" | foreach { gp $_.PSPath } | select DisplayName
```

Comment: are you totally sure that the two are using the same account? if yes, are they using the same privileges?

Comment: Are you running the x86 version of one and the x64 version of the other? This will result in different keys under `"HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"`. You can check by running the x86 and standard version of Windows PowerShell in the Start Menu.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Yes, same account. User account does not have administrator rights. The versions are identical (5.1.18362.752).

Comment: @Ash You are brilliant! That was the issue. Now I have to figure out how to get our self-hosted Azure Devops Release Pipeline to execute Powershell scripts in x86 mode.

Comment: @GeorgeFunke - good to clear that possibility. i see that `Ash` found the real culprit ...32bit versus 64bit. neat diagnostics ... [*grin*]

Comment: @GeorgeFunke Check this out - [Starting the 32-Bit Version of Windows PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/windows-powershell/starting-windows-powershell?view=powershell-7#starting-the-32-bit-version-of-windows-powershell)